# Does a PowerShell subtraction convert uint32 values to int32 internally?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When I wanted to script a subtraction involving two [unit32] variables I got the warning "Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."

A sample to illustrate what I saw

```
$v1 = [uint32]([int32]::MaxValue + 1)
$v2 = [uint32]([int32]::MaxValue + 2)
$v2 - $v1
```

Is this normal behaviour ?
And how can I avoid the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently PowerShell's arithmetic is always signed and does not convert into the next larger type if necessary, indeed. As a workaround you can use `[long]`/`[Int64]`:

```
PS> [long]$v2-$v1
1
```

Or just declare your variables to be  `[long]` initially.

Comment: PowerShell WILL convert to the next largest type if values are not strongly typed.

Answer (score 6):

You are right it's a bit strange. But the correct way of writting it, is the following and it works :

```
PS C:\> $v1 = [uint32]([int32]::MaxValue) + 1
PS C:\> $v2 = [uint32]([int32]::MaxValue) + 2
PS C:\> $v2 -$v1
1
```

The explanation is that `([int32]::MaxValue + 1)` is non sense. If you decompose your first affectation you can see a conversion into a double.

```
PS C:\> $a = ([int32]::MaxValue + 1)
PS C:\> $a.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Double                                   System.ValueType
```

The really strange thing is that if you just add a line it works again.

```
PS C:\> $v1 = [uint32]([int32]::MaxValue + 1)
PS C:\> $v2 = [uint32]([int32]::MaxValue + 2)
PS C:\> $v2 += 1
PS C:\> $v2 - $v1
2
```

You can investigate such expression with the Cmdlet `Trace-Command`:

```
PS C:\> Trace-Command -Name TypeConversion -Expression {[uint32]([int32]::MaxValue + 1)} -PSHost
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 : Converting "64" to "System.Int32".
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 :     Result type is assignable from value to convert's type
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 : Converting "System.Object[]" to "System.Object[]".
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 :     Result type is assignable from value to convert's type
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 : Conversion to System.Type
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 :     Conversion to System.Type
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 :         Found "System.Int32" in the loaded assemblies.
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 : Converting "2147483647" to "System.Double".
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 :     Numeric conversion succeeded.
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 : Converting "1" to "System.Double".
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 :     Numeric conversion succeeded.
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 : Conversion to System.Type
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 :     Conversion to System.Type
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 :         Found "System.UInt32" in the loaded assemblies.
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 : Converting "2147483648" to "System.UInt32".
DÉBOGUER : TypeConversion Information: 0 :     Numeric conversion succeeded.
2147483648
```

Most of the time `Trace-Command` give more informations.

JP